# Data Doesn't Update From API in React/Flux App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm using React + Flux on the frontend for a project and I need to get the username to display it on the sidebar.

The problem: I call the action in the `constructor` of the es6 class which fetches the data needed from the API, and I can see it being logged to the console from the onUserStateChanged method, but it doesn't get updated in the state within the render method.  I don't understand how I can get the state change reflected in the component.

```
export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    UserActions.getCurrentUser();
    this.state = {
      user: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    UserStore.addChangeListener(this.onUserStateChange);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    UserStore.removeChangeListener(this.onUserStateChange);
  }

  onUserStateChange() {
    console.log('called');
    this.state = {
      user: UserStore.getCurrentUser()
    };
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render(){
    var _this = this;
    return (
        console.log(this.state);
        <div>{_this.state.user.username}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

The call to `console.log` from `onUserStateChange()` contains the correct state back from the API whereas the `console.log` in render just shows a blank JS object

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [setState](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

As documentation says:

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

---

Also your constructor seems strange, do you really intend to *not use* the result of `UserActions.getCurrentUser();` in

```
UserActions.getCurrentUser();
this.state = {
  user: {}
};
```

Comment: good call..and I agree about the constructor.  Would the alternative be to use `UserStore.getCurrentUser()` for the `user` property of that object?

Comment: @ironicaldiction You can use `this.state = { user:UserStore.getCurrentUser() }` inside the constructor. This way, the state is also valid before the first `onUserStateChange`. And you don't need to use setState inside the constructor.